# How to query for related object information in Flow to store in a collection

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm attempting to build a screen flow that will display a table of records that are related to the record of the page where the flow is embedded.  In that table of records I want to show related object fields.

For example, the page shows a Widget object. Each Widget is associated with one or more Supplier objects.  Each Supplier object has a ContactID__c field (our main contact at each supplier).  I can easily do a Get Records to retrieve all Supplier records associated with a specific Widget record by filtering on Supplier WidgetId__c = recordId and then display in a data table any of the fields from those Supplier records.

But I also want to show the NAME of each Supplier ContactID.  In SOQL this would be trivial. I can simply add:  ContactID__r.Name to the select clause when querying against the Supplier table/object.

But the GetRecords component in Flow does not support that.

I could take a brute force approach, get the collection of Supplier records, loop through each one and query the Contact record for each Supplier record.  This is inefficient but might be ok as the number of Supplier records per Widget is relatively small.

But I was hoping for a more efficient approach.

Also, even if I take the brute force approach, how/where can I store the Contact information I have retrieved so that it will display in the data table of Supplier records, like showing Contact name and Email address?  I cannot add that information to the Supplier collection returned by the Get Records component.

Comment: There was a different answer that I accepted that is now missing?

Answer (score 0):

I personally just tested this and yes it seems in the data table column selection you could not traverse through the lookup fields. Since, you would only want the name and email address, I would suggest you to **create 2 new formula fields**, in your Supplier object like below:

**Contact Name (ContactID__r.Name), 

Contact Email Address (ContactID__r.Email).** 
Whether you want to show it in the page layout or not, it is up to you.

Now when you get Supplier records, in your data table when you feed this collection in, you can use **Contact Name** and **Contact Email Address** as your column.